# Объединение различных строк html-таблицы

Tags: html, css, table

Моя задача-создать таблицу (`table`), показанную на фото нижe:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно использовать только `html`, а если это невозможно, то можно использовать минимальное количество `css`.
У меня есть проблема, а именно при создании выделенных красным цветом полей в таблице:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как объединить ячейки разных строк в одну ячейку ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Атрибут `rowspan` для тега `<td>` устанавливает число ячеек, которые должны быть объединены по вертикали.

```css
td, th {border:1px solid gray;}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Header column 1</th>
  <th>Header column 2</th>
  <th>Header column 3</th>
  <th>Header column 4</th>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2 - Item 1</td>
    <td>Row 2 - Item 2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Row 2 - Nested Table 1</td>
    <td>Row 2 - Item 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3 Nested Table 2</td>
    <td>Row 3 - Item 2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Row 3 - Item 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 4 - Item 1</td>
    <td>Row 4 - Item 2</td>
    <td>Row 4 - Item 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">Row 5 - Last row of outer table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```